# ScrollView does not show the full content

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am trying to create a chat panel similar to WhatsApp or Telegram.

I have issues where the `ScrollView` does not fully show the top content. If the keyboard is off, it clips a small part (length `x`). When it is open, it clips a bigger content (`x + keyboard's horizontal length`). I don't want to go down the path of calculating the keyboard length dynamically and providing a margin. I could solve the issue by adding SafeAreaView (from `react-native-safe-area-context`), but I also don't want to use that. I think with a few style tricks, I should be able to make it work, but I couldn't do it. I am sharing the whole module:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Button,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const ChatPanel2 = () => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "position" : undefined}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 90 : 0}
      style={{
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
        flex: 1,
        flexGrow: 1,
      }}
    >
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView style={{}}>
          <Text>1- Sentence</Text>
          <Text>
            2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>
            16. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint
            consequatur eos voluptatum et rerum itaque nesciunt inventore
            officia quisquam, asperiores quia laborum nostrum minus
            necessitatibus autem alias molestiae suscipit animi!
          </Text>
          <Text>17. Last</Text>
        </ScrollView>
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <View>
            <TextInput
              style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "black" }}
              textAlignVertical="center"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoFocus={false}
              placeholder="Search here"
            />
          </View>
          <Button
            title="Button"
            onPress={() => {
              console.log("Login");
            }}
          ></Button>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default ChatPanel2;
```

I would love to get your help! Thanks in advance.